# Ruby on Rails - Increment by 1 from last object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, increment, nested-forms

I am building a *user gallery* application, where user can create albums and upload images to their album. I am using `nested forms` for images.

In my `images` database, I have a column called `sort_order`. I want to use `sort_order` to manage the sorting and showing user, for ex: he is seeing **3 of 12** images, where **3** is number of `sort_order` and **12** is number of total images in that album.

`sort_order` is `integer` and `default: 0`. What I looking for is to increase/`increment` number of `sort_order` for each image based on **previous** `sort_order` of last image in same album.

For ex: **image 1** will have `sort_order: 1`, **image 2** will then have previous images sort_id `+1` => `sort_order: 2` and so on.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
after_create :previous_image

  def previous_image

    img = user.images.order("id ASC")

    img.each do |image|
      image.increment!(:sort_order, self.sort_order + 1)
    end

  end
```

This does the work but in wrong sort.

```
id      sort_order
10          3
11          2
12          1
```

instead of having, `id: 10` `sort_order: 1`, its getting `3`.

This is the log:

```
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "sort_order" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "images"."id" = ?  [["sort_order", 1], ["id", 398]]

  user Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 160]]

  Slide Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY id DESC  [["user_id", 160]]

  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "sort_order" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "images"."id" = ?  [["sort_order", 1], ["id", 399]]

  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "sort_order" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "images"."id" = ?  [["sort_order", 2], ["id", 398]]

  user Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 160]]

  Slide Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY id DESC  [["user_id", 160]]

  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "sort_order" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "images"."id" = ?  [["sort_order", 1], ["id", 400]]

  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "sort_order" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "images"."id" = ?  [["sort_order", 2], ["id", 399]]

  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "sort_order" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "images"."id" = ?  [["sort_order", 3], ["id", 398]]
```

It starts from bottom and not top. How can I fix it?

If there is another way to do it without having the `sort_order` column, I am open to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving the form data, add an index (starting from 1) to the images array.

Considering this is your images array from the form:

```
images = [{name: 'Image 1', data: 123}, {name: 'Image 2', data: 456}]
```

Use `with_index(1)` to attach the sort order to every element:

> images.map.with_index(1).to_a

```
=> [[{:name=>"Image 1", :data=>123}, 1], [{:name=>"Image 2", :data=>456}, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Should I add it in my model? I am using `nested_form` as said and doesn't have access to create function for images and each image has its own page. I dont use `each do`

Comment: You have to do this before building/creating your image models